# Return to checkout page after login/register

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help, On my site when guest on a *Checkout page* and press 'Proceed to checkout' then they'll force to Login/Register and they will redirect to /my-account/ but I want them to return to Checkout page.

**Flow:** Checkout page -> Login/Register -> Logged-in --> Checkout page

Comment: You should better add a custom notice on cart page for non logged user using `woocommerce_check_cart_items` hook a bit like in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51282043/3730754) but using `if( ! is_user_logged_in() )` as condition in an if statement. You can't really make the difference between users coming from checkout and other locations, when people get logged in my-account page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this in Logged-in page:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
{
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Online: ';
                header('location: Checkout_Page.php');
    }
```